# How do you tune a suspension air shock on a bike for light riders like me?

Tags: suspension, shocks, small

I recently got a [new bike](https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/nishiki-mens-pueblo-26-mountain-bike-15nisanshkpbl14xxrmb/15nisanshkpbl14xxrmb?color=Gray%2FRed) from Dicks Sporting Goods. I am pretty light and the suspension doesn't even go down. I want mine to be bouncier so this is why I am posting this question.

[image: Right-side view of a Nishiki Men's Pueblo 26" Mountain Bike, a light grey hardtail MTB with red detailing.]

Comment: Generally it is a knob on top of the fork stanchion, however on many cheaper suspension forks with relatively low travel they do not have this option at the consumer level. There are things you could do that involve disassembly but i would not recommend them unless you know what you are doing. The low travel forks on these cheaper bikes are often pretty stiff and really only move much on really hard hits.

Comment: Also, note that this bike is only equipped with 60 mm of travel, so it would make sense that it would be stiff, otherwise it would bottom out the suspension from every little bump that you hit.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specs it does not appear to have an adjustable air shock. Bikes at this price point typically use either a coil spring or a gas strut (similar to the type that holds the hatchback open on a car). The dampening rate is set by the manufacturers design. In some cases larger frame sizes will be stiffer than smaller sizes. The reason being that if you are taller you typically weigh more and need a stiffer suspension. This also means that if you are tall and thinner than average the suspension will be too stiff. Some forks will have a plastic knob that when turned counter-clockwise will give a slightly softer ride. You can try to soften the ride by lowering the pressure in the tires. This can only do so much before you start getting flats from pinching the tubes.

Comment: thanks you very much and i have another question 2 days ago I heard some squealing from my friend's bike and we are trying to fix it. It looks like it's coming from the rim brakes

Comment: Please consider viewing the "Tour" section that explains how to search for answers to previously asked questions. If nothing seems be an issue similar to yours you can post another question about that specific issue.